# Рекурсивная функция не меняет значение в массиве

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели, рекурсия

Рекурсивная функция rec_copy(int(*arr_input)[dim], int(*arr_output)[dim], int i, int j) должна копировать из первого массива (arr_input) во второй (arr_output) значения, совпадающие с заданным значением идентификатора sign.
Часть необходимого кода выполняет функция rec_line_copy, вызывающаяся в основной функции rec_copy для обработки отдельной "строки" массива. Рекурсивная функция rec_copy вызывает в себе функцию rec_line_copy, после чего вызывает сама себя в том случае, если обработаны не все "строки" массива.
Проблема состоит в том, что функция rec_line_copy по какой-то непонятной мне причине никогда не изменяет элементы второго массива, несмотря на то, что находит совпадающие с sign элементы. В чем причина, подскажите, пожалуйста?

```
#define dim   81
#define sign   1

void rec_line_copy(int(*arr_input)[dim], int(*arr_output)[dim], int i, int j) {
    if (j < dim) {
        if ((*(*(arr_input + i) + j)) == sign) *(*(arr_output + i) + j) =sign;
        rec_line_copy(arr_input, arr_input, i, j + 1);
    }

}
void rec_copy(int(*arr_input)[dim], int(*arr_output)[dim], int i, int j) {
    rec_line_copy(arr_input, arr_output, i, 0);
    if (i < dim - 1) rec_copy(arr_input, arr_output, i + 1, 0);
}
int main() {
    int i = 0, step = 0;
    int A[dim][dim], B[dim][dim];
    int(*p_arrA)[dim];
    int(*p_arrB)[dim];
    p_arrA = A;
    p_arrB = B;
    rec_copy(p_arrA, p_arrB, 0, 0);
    scanf("%i", &i);
}
```

Comment: @AnT according to E.A.Poe - look at the bold part of the question

Comment: Так а инициализация массива где? И зачем в коде применен этот иноплянетянский синтаксис `*(*(arr_output + i) + j)`? Почему не написать просто по человечески `arr_output[i][j]`?

Comment: как в массивы попадают значения?

Comment: @AnT, выделил как код объявление dim и sign. Инопланетянский синтаксис - это указатели, без которых, насколько мне известно, нельзя в принципе изменить значение в массиве через функцию.

Comment: @Igor,@AnT значения массивов заданы подобными рекурсивными функциями, которые точно работают и не вызывают никаких проблем. Я не вставил их в вопрос, чтобы не нагромождать кучу кода. Нужно было?

Comment: @R2B9 Уже - нет ).

Comment: Синтаксис `*(*(arr_output + i) + j)` абсолютно стопроцентно эквивалентен синтаксису `arr_output[i][j]`. При чем здесь "указатели" - не ясно.

Comment: @AnT, я залагал, когда писал про указатели. 
Я просто почему-то привык при работе с указателями и массивами писать именно так: *(*(arr_output + i) + j). Не знал, что это не обязательно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После Copy/Paste забыли исправить название второго параметра:

`rec_line_copy(arr_input,` **arr_input**`, i, j + 1);`

Comment: спасибо вам. Все заработало идеально.Сидел над этой непонятно откуда взявшейся проблемой около получаса и не понимал, что тут может быть не так. Видимо, пора идти спать, невнимательность на максимуме.

Comment: @R2B9 На здоровье. Перед тем, как идти спать - слева от ответа знак "галочка".